# Return a list that only includes duplicate elements

Tags: list, prolog

**I am not allowed to use any built-in ProLog list predicates.**
I am just starting out with ProLog and was given the following exercise:

Write a predicate ***repeated(L,D)*** where **D** is a list of all values that have duplicates in the list **L**.

```
?- repeated([a,b,a,d,a,d],D).
D = [a,d].
```

Please help, I've been stuck on this for a pretty long time now ://
THANK YOU!!

Comment: Something is repeated if it appears in the part of the list following its first occurrence (i.e. `a` is in `[b,a,d,a,d]`, `b` is in `[a,d,a,d]`: translate that into Prolog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the answer suggested by [Nicholas Carey's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70072701/7502914) does not output exactly `[a, d]`, but `[b, a, d]`.

However, inspired by him, I updated the logic and here is the working code:

```
repeated( []     , []     ) .
repeated( [X|Xs] , [X|Ds] ) :- 
    repeated(Xs, Ds), 
    contains(X, Xs), negate(contains(X, Ds)), !.      % <--- New logic here
repeated( [_|Xs] ,    Ds  ) :- repeated(Xs, Ds).

contains(X, [X|_] ).
contains(X, [_|Xs] ) :- contains(X,Xs).
negate(X) :- \+ X.
```

The logic of the modified version is to ensure that the first element `X` has a duplicate in the list `Xs`. And **also** ensure that it is not already in the "return" list `Ds`.

Example of working queries:

```
?- repeated([a,b,a,23,1432,5,25,23,23,24,23,25,25,21,d,a,d], D).
D = [a, 23, 25, d]
?- repeated([a, b, b, b, b], D).
D = [b]
```

---

`contains/2` is just a custom implementation of `member/2`.

`negate/1` is just a custom implementation of `not/1`.

Answer (score 0):

Break it down. Most recursive problems have 1 or 2 special, terminating cases and the general case.

So...

The special, terminating case is the empty list. It contains no duplicate items:

```
repeated( [] , [] ) .
```

The general case is this:

The head of the list is a duplicate, iff...

- it can be found in the tail of the list.

So, we need a way to identify the dupe:

```
is_duplicate(X,Xs) :- \+ contains(X,Xs) .

contains(X, [X|Xs] ).
contains(X, [_|Xs] ) :- contains(X,Xs).
```

[Incidentally, `contains/2` is essentially the implementation of the built-in `member/2`.]

Once we have that, implementing the general recursive case is easy. We just traverse the list and find the duplicates:

```
repeated( [X|Xs] , [X|Ds] ) :- is_duplicate(X,Xs), !, repeated(Xs,Ds) .
repeated( [_|Xs] ,    Ds  ) :- repeated(Xs,Ds).
```

The cut (`!/0`) is there to eliminate the choice point: If `X` is a duplicate, we don't want to try the 3rd/last alternative on backtracking.

If you put that together, you get this:

```
repeated( []     , []     ) .
repeated( [X|Xs] , [X|Ds] ) :- is_duplicate(X,Xs), !, repeated(Xs,Ds) .
repeated( [_|Xs] ,    Ds  ) :- repeated(Xs,Ds).

is_duplicate(X,Xs) :- \+ contains(X,Xs) .

contains(X, [X|Xs] ).
contains(X, [_|Xs] ) :- contains(X,Xs).
```